# EMACS encoding issues Windows 11

Tags: ess, character-encoding

I am having encoding issues with EMACS (ESS). Part of the problem is that many of my file paths contain a special character (ý). These characters keep getting converted to "Ã½" when I close and reopen the buffer.

`C-h v buffer-file-coding-system RET` used to give:

```
Its value is ‘iso-latin-1-unix’
Local in buffer file.r; global value is iso-latin-1-dos
```

I added `(setq-default buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)` to my init.el file, and now
`C-h v buffer-file-coding-system RET` gives:

```
Its value is ‘iso-latin-1-unix’
Local in buffer file.r; global value is utf-8-unix
```

If I correct the letters and use `C-x RET r utf-8-unix RET` they get re-written as `\375`.

I added the following lines to my init.el
(setq-default buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
(setq-default coding-system-for-read 'utf-8-unix)
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
And now
`C-h v buffer-file-coding-system RET` gives:

```
Its value is ‘utf-8-unix’
Local in buffer file.r; global value is the same.
```

but R in EMACS ESS no longer works.
Shift-enter to start the minor process and execute a line of R code causes EMACS to freeze and all I get is a spinning wheel until I force quit.

So I removed those lines from my init.el to restore R.
When I start R there is a error message "Error: invalid multibyte character in parser at line 1" which has to do with `setwd()` as the file path has the character ý in it.

If I put `file.r` into a directory that does not have `ý` in the path, everything works correctly.

Comment: Don't put the answer in the question. Post it separately as an answer. You can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding these three lines to my init file:

```lisp
(setq-default buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8) <br/> 
(setq-default coding-system-for-read 'utf-8) <br/> 
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
```

Comment: Jacob, this saves me a lot, thank you for posting it. Where did you find that these three were needed? (I'm looking for a canonical link in case I also run into other utf-based issues in emacs.) Thanks!

Comment: No specific place, just some various bits on this site and trial and error